# How to write a clear proof that if $N$ is a normal subgroup whose quotient group is abelian, the commutator subgroup is a subset of $N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to find the right level of explicitness to use when writing algebra proofs.  The challenge is that algebra proofs, once complete, can often devolve into simply a series of equations.  But adding too much explanation can be distracting.

For example, when working on:

> If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian, prove that the commutator subgroup $[G, G]$ is a subset of $N$.

I wrote the proof below, trying to strike the right balance of being clear and explicit, while still being succinct.  I tried to justify each step in a way which still kept the compactness of formulation inherent to algebra.

Have I done that well? How could the exposition be improved? (Of course, I should first ask if it is *correct*.)

Note: Proofs of this fact may be available; this question is about the exposition (and verification) of *this* proof.

Note 2: Also germane to this question is: How to properly write proofs of this nature - balancing between strings of symbolic equations and words.  I considered asking this as a separate question, but concluded that it needed to be discussed in the context of a specific problem.  Hence, this question.

---

**Proof:** Recall that $x$ is a member of subgroup $N$ if and only if $xN = N$.  It therefore suffices to show that $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}N = N$ for all $g, h \in N$.  We have:

$$\begin{align*}
ghg^{-1}h^{-1}N &= ghg^{-1}h^{-1}NN \quad \text{($N$ is a subgroup)} \\
&= ghNg^{-1}Nh^{-1} \quad \text{($N$ is normal)} \\
&= ghNh^{-1}Ng^{-1} \quad \text{($G/N$ is abelian)} \\
&= ghh^{-1}g^{-1}NN \quad \text{($$N is normal)} \\
& = N.
\end{align*}$$

---

## Update

I gather from the initial comments and answer that the answer depends on the anticipated audience.  That makese sense.

What would be most helpful is to *teach by example*: Present an alternate exposition of the proof above, perhaps shorter, perhaps longer, but that illustrates how you'd write this (at least for whatever audience you choose).

Comment: I hope you remember that not every element of $[G,G]$ is a commutator though. If you want a formal proof, you need to add that since $N$ contains a generating set of $[G,G]$, it contains the whole subgroup.

Comment: @Mark This is a great example of what I'm grappling with.  I was distinctly aware of the point you raise, but wasn't sure if it should be mentioned.  In fact, my first draft of the proof didn't even have the "Recall..." statement, but just started "It suffices to show...".  The question is: Many texts seem to make those types of shortcuts, saying "It suffices to show...".  Can I do that? Or do I need to spell out each step _why_? What is the criteria to write a step versus tacitly imply it?

Comment: Depends where do you write it. In an exam it is better to write with all details. In a textbook it is fine to write that it suffices to show that, as in this example it really should be clear why this is sufficient. However, some authors sadly take this a bit too far and sometimes skip lots of "obvious" details which then take hours, if not days to understand.

Comment: Your edit essentially includes my answer. You should try writing different proofs for different audiences. What  would you want to see  in a textbook? What would you write for a friend who was struggling in this course? What would you want to see from a student when you teach this course (some day)?

Comment: $1=[G/N,G/N]=([G,G]N)/N$. Then necessarily $[G,G]\subseteq N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a meta answer to this question. The *right level of explicitness* in a proof depends on the reason you are writing the proof.

If it's an exercise in a course, its purpose is to show the instructor that you understand precisely why the theorem is true. Your proof in the question does that. I  think strings of symbols are rarely the best way to write proofs, but in this case that works just fine.

If it's a proof in a textbook, or a more interesting course exercise, I think more motivation and more words would be better.

If it's part of a research paper in a journal, "left to the reader" would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you write the above with _more motivation and more words_?

Comment: In a paper, for this particular example, I would write "by the universal properties of the commutator subgroup" (which isn't much longer than "left to the reader" and is a little more insightful).

Comment: And do you agree with the comment above that I should also state explicitly that the generating elements of $[G,G]$ are precisely the set of $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, and since $N$ includes every generating element of $[G,G]$, then $N$ include $[G,G]$? Or feel the write up above is good, at least for a course exercise?

Comment: @RobArthan Agreed. My point was more "this kind of calculation is left to the reader" rather than a comment on this particular proof.

Comment: @SRobertJames  My answer really addresses the meta question, not this particular proof. Others note that you should state that explicitly, As an instructor I would have wanted a few more words from you, but not complained. In my class there would be many exercises that clearly called for more analysis.